# Cannot instantiate ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

"Cannont instantiate the type ActionListener" The code works in my Fahrenheit panel class...does as it supposed to. I am trying to make the PigLatin use a GUI as well like Fahrenheit does...but it returns with that error...do i need a different type of listener? I tried text listener and multi but that didnt work. I have a Fahrenheit class that creates a GUI displaying the conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius and that works with the ActionListener(new TempListener) and no errors. I know that an interface cannot be instantiated like an object, but why can I do it in my other class?

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class PigLatinTranslator extends JPanel 
{

    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
       private JTextField piglatin;

    public PigLatinTranslator()
    {

    inputLabel = new JLabel ("What would you like to translate:");
    outputLabel = new JLabel ("Pig Latin translation: ");
    resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");

    piglatin = new JTextField (5);
    piglatin.addActionListener (new MyActionListener());

    add (inputLabel);
    add (piglatin);
    add (outputLabel);
    add (resultLabel);

    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 75));
    setBackground (Color.red);

    }
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Translates a sentence of words into Pig Latin.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static String translate (String sentence)
   {
      String result = "";

      sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

      Scanner scan = new Scanner (sentence);

      while (scan.hasNext())
      {
         result += translateWord (scan.next());
         result += " ";
      }

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Translates one word into Pig Latin. If the word begins with a
   //  vowel, the suffix "yay" is appended to the word.  Otherwise,
   //  the first letter or two are moved to the end of the word,
   //  and "ay" is appended.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private static String translateWord (String word)
   {
      String result = "";

      if (beginsWithVowel(word))
         result = word + "yay";
      else
         if (beginsWithBlend(word))
            result = word.substring(2) + word.substring(0,2) + "ay";
         else
            result = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Determines if the specified word begins with a vowel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private static boolean beginsWithVowel (String word)
   {
      String vowels = "aeiou";

      char letter = word.charAt(0);

      return (vowels.indexOf(letter) != -1);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Determines if the specified word begins with a particular
   //  two-character consonant blend.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private static boolean beginsWithBlend (String word)
   {
      return ( word.startsWith ("bl") || word.startsWith ("sc") ||
               word.startsWith ("br") || word.startsWith ("sh") ||
               word.startsWith ("ch") || word.startsWith ("sk") ||
               word.startsWith ("cl") || word.startsWith ("sl") ||
               word.startsWith ("cr") || word.startsWith ("sn") ||
               word.startsWith ("dr") || word.startsWith ("sm") ||
               word.startsWith ("dw") || word.startsWith ("sp") ||
               word.startsWith ("fl") || word.startsWith ("sq") ||
               word.startsWith ("fr") || word.startsWith ("st") ||
               word.startsWith ("gl") || word.startsWith ("sw") ||
               word.startsWith ("gr") || word.startsWith ("th") ||
               word.startsWith ("kl") || word.startsWith ("tr") ||
               word.startsWith ("ph") || word.startsWith ("tw") ||
               word.startsWith ("pl") || word.startsWith ("wh") ||
               word.startsWith ("pr") || word.startsWith ("wr") ); 
   }

}





import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FahrenheitPanel extends JPanel
{
   private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
   private JTextField fahrenheit;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the main GUI components.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public FahrenheitPanel()
   {
      inputLabel = new JLabel ("Enter Fahrenheit temperature:");
      outputLabel = new JLabel ("Temperature in Celsius: ");
      resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");

      fahrenheit = new JTextField (5);
      fahrenheit.addActionListener (new TempListener());

      add (inputLabel);
      add (fahrenheit);
      add (outputLabel);
      add (resultLabel);

      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 75));
      setBackground (Color.yellow);
   }

   //*****************************************************************
   //  Represents an action listener for the temperature input field.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class TempListener implements ActionListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Performs the conversion when the enter key is pressed in
      //  the text field.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {
         int fahrenheitTemp, celsiusTemp;

         String text = fahrenheit.getText();

         fahrenheitTemp = Integer.parseInt (text);
         celsiusTemp = (fahrenheitTemp-32) * 5/9;

         resultLabel.setText (Integer.toString (celsiusTemp));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where's `MyActionListener`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Fahrenheit is runnable I said that I didn't put the full code I'll put it up

Comment: @Sam what has the fact that Fahreneit is runnable to do with the problem? Check my answer... You're missing a class here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyActionListener()` is not an inner class of `PigLatinTranslator`, that is your problem (it doesn't exist).

If you put your `class` in another file, provide it but basically, if you're using this code only, the problem you're facing is the fact that you haven't created the `MyActionListener()` class yet.

You know how to do it, I'm not providing the code of course.

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PigLatinTranslator extends JPanel 
{

    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel;
       private JTextField piglatin;

    public PigLatinTranslator()
    {

    inputLabel = new JLabel ("What would you like to translate:");
    outputLabel = new JLabel ("Pig Latin translation: ");
    resultLabel = new JLabel ("---");

    piglatin = new JTextField (5);
    piglatin.addActionListener (new LangListener());

    add (inputLabel);
    add (piglatin);
    add (outputLabel);
    add (resultLabel);

    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 75));
    setBackground (Color.red);

    }
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Translates a sentence of words into Pig Latin.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    public static String translate (String sentence)
   {
      String result = "";

      sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

      Scanner scan = new Scanner (sentence);

      while (scan.hasNext())
      {
         result += translateWord (scan.next());
         result += " ";
      }

      return result;
   }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Translates one word into Pig Latin. If the word begins with a
   //  vowel, the suffix "yay" is appended to the word.  Otherwise,
   //  the first letter or two are moved to the end of the word,
   //  and "ay" is appended.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
  private static String translateWord (String word)
   {
      String result = "";

      if (beginsWithVowel(word))
         result = word + "yay";
      else
         if (beginsWithBlend(word))
            result = word.substring(2) + word.substring(0,2) + "ay";
         else
            result = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";

      return result;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Determines if the specified word begins with a vowel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private static boolean beginsWithVowel (String word)
   {
      String vowels = "aeiou";

      char letter = word.charAt(0);

      return (vowels.indexOf(letter) != -1);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Determines if the specified word begins with a particular
   //  two-character consonant blend.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private static boolean beginsWithBlend (String word)
   {
      return ( word.startsWith ("bl") || word.startsWith ("sc") ||
               word.startsWith ("br") || word.startsWith ("sh") ||
               word.startsWith ("ch") || word.startsWith ("sk") ||
               word.startsWith ("cl") || word.startsWith ("sl") ||
               word.startsWith ("cr") || word.startsWith ("sn") ||
               word.startsWith ("dr") || word.startsWith ("sm") ||
               word.startsWith ("dw") || word.startsWith ("sp") ||
               word.startsWith ("fl") || word.startsWith ("sq") ||
               word.startsWith ("fr") || word.startsWith ("st") ||
               word.startsWith ("gl") || word.startsWith ("sw") ||
               word.startsWith ("gr") || word.startsWith ("th") ||
               word.startsWith ("kl") || word.startsWith ("tr") ||
               word.startsWith ("ph") || word.startsWith ("tw") ||
               word.startsWith ("pl") || word.startsWith ("wh") ||
               word.startsWith ("pr") || word.startsWith ("wr") ); 
   }


   private class LangListener implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {
              String text = piglatin.getText();

                 resultLabel.setText(translate(text));
   }
}}



import java.util.Scanner;


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PigLatin
{


   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Reads sentences and translates them into Pig Latin. 
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Pig Latin");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          PigLatinTranslator panel = new PigLatinTranslator();

          frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   {
          String input, result, another;

          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

          do
          {
             System.out.println ();
             System.out.println ("Enter a sentence (no punctuation):");
             input = scan.nextLine();

             System.out.println ();
             result = PigLatinTranslator.translate (input);
             System.out.println ("That sentence in Pig Latin is:");
             System.out.println (result);

             System.out.println ();
             System.out.print ("Translate another sentence (y/n)? ");
             another = scan.nextLine();
          }
          while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
       }



}
```